# C++ compiler issue with struct in template class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, compiler-bug

The following code does **not** compile with gcc or clang.

```
template<class T>
class foo{};

template<class T>
class template_class_with_struct
{
    void my_method() {
        if(this->b.foo < 1);
    };

    struct bar
    {
        long foo;
    } b;
};
```

Error message is

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> class foo'    
    8 |         if(this->b.foo < 1);
```

The error is caused by templat class foo. When writing <= instead of < 1 it also compiles.

Any hint appreciated?

CompilerExplorer link https://godbolt.org/z/v6Tygo

Comment: I would say compiler bugs but msvc is the only one to accept it :-/ [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yap6k5). Possible Work arounds [`b.bar::foo`](https://godbolt.org/z/SUUS8z) or [parenthesis (`(this->b.foo) < 1`)](https://godbolt.org/z/VX95GW)

Answer (score 1):

In GCC, I get

```
so.cpp:8:27: error: expected '>'
    if(this->b.foo < 1) 
                      ^
```

So, the compiler thinks that the `foo` on that line refers to the class `foo` above and is expecting a template argument. This is similar to what you are seeing.

When you change it to `<=`, which is tokenized by the lexer as a single token. The next stage does not even see a `<`, so it is not confused by it.

If you change the class to not have the same name as the long in `bar`, then it doesn't have this issue. Also, @Jarod42 has suggestions in his comment to your question (more qualification or parens).

Compilers are written in stages, where each stage translates the code to a better representation for the next, and each stage can do more and more complex things with that representation.

At the start, the compiler "lexes" the code, which turns the individual characters in the file into a stream of tokens -- it would see this line as something like

```
// if(this->b.foo < 1) 
- keyword(if)
- left-paren
- keyword(this)
- operator(->)
- name(b)
- operator(.)
```

And then it gets to the `foo`.  It should probably do

```
- name(foo)
- operator(<)
- number(1)
- right-paren
```

But, it looks to me like when it sees `foo`, it looks ahead, sees the `<` and the fact that `foo<class T>` exists and it tries to make a single token out of `foo< ...` but then it can't find the `>` to complete it.

This is just a guess -- it could be a stage past the lexer that tries to find names and can combine tokens.  In any case, the multiple uses of foo is tricking it.

Comment: I understand your explanation, but not sure if it means the compiler should behave that way. Maybe this should be field as bug for the different compilers. Sometimes you can't be aware of what template classes are within a linked library header ( common names like cnt, count, counter ...)

Comment: I think it's a bug, but I don't know what the spec says.  Having names from 3rd party headers cause issues is a common occurrence in C++ -- you can usually resolve with qualification.